# "CURLE_OUT_OF_MEMORY" error when posting via https

Tags: c++, curl, https, openssl

I am attempting to write an application that uses libCurl to post soap requests to a secure web service.  This Windows application is built against libCurl version 7.19.0 which, in turn, is built against openssl-0.9.8i.  The pertinent curl related code follows:

> ```
> FILE *input_file = fopen(current->post_file_name.c_str(), "rb");
> FILE *output_file = fopen(current->results_file_name.c_str(), "wb");
> if(input_file && output_file)
> {
>     struct curl_slist *header_opts = 0;
>     CURLcode rcd;
>
>     header_opts = curl_slist_append(header_opts, "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf8");
>     curl_easy_reset(curl_handle);
>     curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
>     curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, output_file);
>     curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_READDATA, input_file);
>     curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, fs_service_url);
>     curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
>     curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header_opts);
>     rcd = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
>     if(rcd != 0)
>     {
>         current->curl_result = rcd;
>         current->curl_error = curl_easy_strerror(rcd);
>     }
>     curl_slist_free_all(header_opts);
> }
> ```

When I attempt to execute the URL, curl returns an CURLE_OUT_OF_MEMORY error which appears to be related to a failure to allocate an SSL context.  Has anyone else encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation, I found that this error was due to a failure to initialise the openSSL library by calling SSL_library_init().

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, just thought I'd add the note that rather than calling the OpenSsl export SSL_library_init directly it can be fixed by adding the flag CURL_GLOBAL_SSL to [curl_global_init](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same symptom after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37295100/363437). The solution was to Use TLS like so.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2));
```

Apparently SSLv3 [was disabled](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.2g-1ubuntu1) on Ubuntu 16.04.