# Initializing SSL and libcurl and getting "out of memory"

Tags: c++, ssl, libcurl

I intend to do https requests with libcurl and openssl with a C++ program.

I initialized libcurl with `curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL)` as described in the documentation. Then I use an `curl_easy` handle that I initialize, populate with headers and a body, and send everything  out to ´https://example.com:443/foo´. It works for non-https connections.

[Looking around](http://curl-library.cool.haxx.narkive.com/RwCtIULD/https-request-with-curl-library-gives-out-of-memory-error) I find that there may be other libraries that are already getting an SSL context which is what causes libcurl to fail in doing precisely that. I get the following error message:

```
curl_easy_perform failed: Out of memory
```

In my case I am using [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) which I initialize with

```
mhdDaemon = MHD_start_daemon(MHD_USE_THREAD_PER_CONNECTION | MHD_USE_SSL,
                               htons(port),
                               NULL,
                               NULL,
                               connectionTreat,                     NULL,
                               MHD_OPTION_HTTPS_MEM_KEY,            httpsKey,
                               MHD_OPTION_HTTPS_MEM_CERT,           httpsCertificate,
                               MHD_OPTION_CONNECTION_MEMORY_LIMIT,  memoryLimit,
                               MHD_OPTION_SOCK_ADDR,                (struct sockaddr*) &sad,
                               MHD_OPTION_NOTIFY_COMPLETED,         requestCompleted, NULL,
                               MHD_OPTION_END);
```

So I am indeed using openSSL somewhere else. The thing is, if I take out the `MHD_USE_SSL` part it does not fix the problem.

This is the list of libraries that are linked to the application (I'm using cmake):

```
-lmicrohttpd
-lmongoclient
-lboost_thread
-lboost_filesystem
-lboost_system
-lpthread
```

Is there any of the others that could be loading SSL? Is microhttpd loading it anyways even if I comment out the `MHD_USE_SSL` flag (plus all other related flags)? Could there be any other reason for this error?

Comment: I have not had problems using Curl and OpenSSL in combination with other libraries that also use OpenSSL..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of *any* problem in libcurl that would cause this error code to get returned if indeed a memory allocation function doesn't fail. Using OpenSSL in multiple modules does not cause such a failure. (I am the lead developer of libcurl.)

So, run your app with VERBOSE set to libcurl, or even strace to see which syscall that fails and it should give you more clues.

Comment: Thanks to your pointers I was able to find the solutions. I just needed to initialize openSSL library with `SSL_library_init()` before any use of it by other the other libraries.

Comment: This comment looks like the answer (not the ticked answer).

Answer (score 0):

As the descibed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048885/initializing-ssl-and-libcurl-and-getting-out-of-memory/37295100#37295100), you might need to disable SSLv3 if you are on Ubuntu 16.04 like so

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2));
```

It was disabled on Ubuntu 16.04 for security reasons, see more [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.2g-1ubuntu1).